# Nightmare with passing inheritance through WCF

Tags: wcf, icloneable

We have a class in WCF Service like the following

```
[DataContract]
public class SampleClass:ICloneable
{ public object Clone()  { return MemberwiseClone(); } .... }
```

On client side where Service References added, I open the Reference in Object Browser, but 
it didn't pass ICloneable as an inherited Interface like "IExtensibleDataObject"

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="SampleClass",
Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestService")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class SampleClass : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject,
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged { .... }
```

Is there anyone know how can I pass it?

Comment: WCF is meant to pass messages (data), not object implementation or inheritance. Do you have the option to use the assembly that defines SampleClass on the client side? Deploying the server side implementation assembly on the client is the easiest answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can't and shouldn't be passed. Whether or not an object implements `ICloneable` isn't part of the service contract. The server doesn't care if the client is cloning objects, nor can it supply an implementation for the clone operation.

If you want your objects to be cloneable, you'll have to supply an implementation on the *client* side -- note that the class is `partial`, so you can simply create a new file that reads:

```
public partial class SampleClass : ICloneable {
    public object Clone() { 
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have to do this for all generated types, it could be a pain. If you are writing the service as well (or have access to the source) and that already contains the correct `Clone` implementations, you can use the same classes in both client and server by putting them in a separate assembly. This is not completely trivial because you need to work around some stubbornness in Visual Studio; see "[WCF and Shared Reference Library Between Client & Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974470/wcf-and-shared-reference-library-between-client-service)" for more details.

Note that [the MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable):

> The `ICloneable` interface simply requires that your implementation of
>   the `Clone` method return a copy of the current object instance. It does
>   not specify whether the cloning operation performs a deep copy, a
>   shallow copy, or something in between. Nor does it require all
>   property values of the original instance to be copied to the new
>   instance. For example, the `NumberFormatInfo.Clone` method performs a
>   shallow copy of all properties except the `NumberFormatInfo.IsReadOnly`
>   property; it always sets this property value to false in the cloned
>   object. Because callers of `Clone` cannot depend on the method
>   performing a predictable cloning operation, we recommend that
>   `ICloneable` not be implemented in public APIs.

If you need an object to be cloneable, you can still implement your own `Clone` method (and use `MemberwiseClone` if this is appropriate) but there is probably no good reason to use `ICloneable`.

Comment: It's 2 am on Thanksgiving night and I messed up your correct answer! and accidentaly wrote on it instead of put comment, sorry about that